# fluent-ffmpeg frames disappear after the merge

Tags: javascript, video, merge, fluent-ffmpeg

I have a problem with the function `mergeToFile()` of the library `fluent-ffmpeg`. If you use the `mergeToFile` function several times, then in the merged video, the frames are lost. Sometimes the video is cut off for a few seconds.

```
fluent_ffmpeg()
  .addInput('video1.webm')
  .addInput('video2.webm')
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('Success!');
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
  })
  .mergeToFile('result.webm');
```

I've tried other additional options, but they didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a decision, maybe it will be useful. The function mergeToFile() works correctly only for the first time. However, if you write the result of merge in the file and delete the file specified in arguments of function .mergeToFile(), it will work.

```js
fluent_ffmpeg()
  .addInput('video1.webm')
  .addInput('video2.webm')
  .on('end', function() {
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('video1.webm', {encoding: 'binary'});
    writeStream.on('close', function() {
      fs.unlinkSync('result.webm');
    });
    fs.createReadStream('result.webm').pipe(writeStream);
  })
  .mergeToFile('result.webm');
```